# Code runs on command prompt but not on hydrogen

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt, try-except, hydrogen

I'm just beginning with programming(python3), using the information available on Internet. Right now I'm learning how to use try/except. My problem is that the code I wrote runs fine in the command prompt of windows 10, but not in the shell(Atom/Hydrogen) where it throws an error(line 6, NameError) because I didn't defined the variable "fish", I know that usually happened the other way around but I just want to understand if I'm making a mistake.  The code is as follows:

```
>try:
>>    fish = int (input("please enter your age "))
>except:
>>    print("That's not a number ")
>>    exit(0)
>if fish <= 15:
>>    parentLicense = input ("have one of your parents have a license? (yes/no) ")
>>    if parentLicense == "yes":
>>>        print ("You can fish")
>>    else:
>>>        print("So sad, you or one of your parents need a license")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Chiron and welcome to the community. The reason you are getting an undefined error is because fish can be undifined under certain circumstances in the try statement.
You should use

```
try:
    # try stuff
except ValueError:
    # do stuff when theres an error
else:
    # stuff if try stuff works
```

else is only called if no exception is raised. I would avoid using bare except too as it can cause issues and its not good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcoming.Very useful the advice about the "except" without specifications, I didn't know it is not a good practice, I found it useful for an input statement, specially in order to avoid python's default error message.

Comment: @Chiron you're welcome, if the answer helped solve the issue please accept it as the answer :)